# React-Native "expected a component class, got object Object"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a big code that does not run because of the error in the headline.
This is one file of my code, can anyone see what is wrong? I believe it is the line "{this.state.todos.map((todo,index) =>" (code line 62)

I have capitalised the name of the objects, so that is not the issue (I think). 
npm -v 4.6.1

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import $ from 'jquery';
import { Button, View,  FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-svg'

/* generating sample data to be shown, these data names are used to access the values*/
var todos = [];

//Will not work first time, since list do not exist in AsyncStorage. 
//Get from AsyncStorage. 
try{
  todos = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage["todos"]);
}catch(ex){
  console.log("Not working" + ex);
  todos = [];
}

//Errormessage for errorhandeling. 
var errorMessage = "";
/*--------------------*/

class Todos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos
    };

    this.handleAddTodo = this.handleAddTodo.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddTodo(todo) {
    /* creates todo in list that shows*/
    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos, todo]});
    /*this code saves in AsyncStorage*/
    todos.push(todo);
    //AsyncStorage...
    AsyncStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }


/* function that removes todos from the list*/
  handleRemoveTodo(index) {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter(function(e, i) {
        return i !== index;
      })
    })
    /* now working as expected*/
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    AsyncStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TodosInput onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo} />
        <hr />
          <Text>todo count: <span>{this.state.todos.length}</span></Text>
          <View>
            <View>{this.state.todos.map((todo,index) =>
              <View key={index}>
                <Text style={style.list-group-item-heading}>{todo.todoTitle}<small><span style={style.label} label-info></span></small>  </Text>

                <View>{todo.todoDesc}</View>

                <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={this.handleRemoveTodo.bind(this, index)}><span style={style.glyphicon} glyphicon-trash></span></Button>
              </View>
            )}</View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely because of using html tags instead of native components.
Like `hr` `span` and `small`.

So you need to create your own components and also titlecase their names.
Here is possible example how to fix your problem:

```js
const Small = ({ children }) => (
  <Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 10
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </Text>
);

const HR = () => (
  <View
    style={{
      height: 1,
      borderBottomColor: "black",
      borderBottomWidth: 1
    }}
  />
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Text>This is span</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>
            Regular test <Small>With {"<small>"} text</Small> Inside
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>This is {"<HR />"} bellow</Text>
          <HR />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPD:** Actually there are a lot of other bugs in a code above

Quick list of possible issues:

1. as pointed dalready - replace all html tags with native components
2. `style={style.list-group-item-heading}` You cannot use dash separator in js except ni a strings - possible fix: `style={style['list-group-item-heading']}`
3. `<View>{todo.todoDesc}</View>` - you have to wrao text with `Text` compnent
4. `<Button />` component have required prop `title` it should be a string, as well as it dosn't have `OnClick` handler but requires `OnPress`

To summarize  - i would note that react native uses jsx but it is not html. It have its own API and you'll have to grasp it carefully.